# Unable to load JSON data for Cities gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rubygems

I am using the [Cities](https://github.com/joecorcoran/cities) gem for allowing the users to select their city.

According to the documentation the path to the JSON data should be set using the following line of code.

```
Cities.data_path = '/path/to/cities'
```

I am not able to figure out where to add it and how to load. I've tried adding the line with the location of json files in my app directory but no luck. I still get the error, "not able to load JSON data".

I am a beginner and as you can see the documentation is not much beginner friendly.

Comment: Did you download the cities.tar.gz file and untar it as it describes in the help? I am assuming that the cities file is provided in that tar file.

Comment: @punkle yes, that was the first thing I did.

Comment: And have you set ```Cities.data_path``` to the path where the cities directory was untarred?

Comment: That is what I want to know, where do I add the data_path line to set the path. I tried adding it in a new file in the initializers but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

what you usually do in rails is to create an [initializer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html) file in `config/initializers`, give it a proper name like `cities.rb` and put the code in there.

Comment: If my JSON data is in the app/assets/json directory then do I also add #{Rails.path} in the address or normally with /app/assets/json ?

Comment: whenever you reference something in your app you do it relative from the app root directory `Rails.root.join('config/the_cities_json_file.json')`. only put stuff in `app/assets` that is used to be delivered via HTTP to the client like images, css and javascript.